# Adding column to pandas dataframe using group name in function when iterating through groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a set of data which I fitted using a function, this yielded a dict with fitting parameters where the keys correspond to the possible group names.

Imagine I have another dataframe with some of those groups and some corresponding x-values. What I would like to do is get the y-values for the x-values in the second dataset using the fitting parameters from the dict, without merging the parameters onto the second dataset.

Here is a simplified example of what I would like to do. First I have a function using fitting parameters (not the real one):

```python
def func(x,p):
    y = 0
    for i in range(len(p)):
        y += p[i]*x**(i)
    return y
```

A DataFrame with the second dataset consisting of two columns to group on and some corresponding x-values:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(3, size=20),
                   'b': np.random.randint(3, size=20),
                   'x': np.random.randint(10, high=20, size=20)})
```

A dict with fitting parameters (groups of df are typically a sample of the dict keys):

```python
params = {key: np.random.randint(5,size=3) for key in df.groupby(['a','b']).groups.keys()}
```

Now I want to calculate a new column 'ycalc', using the group names as selector for params and apply the function. In my head this would look something like:

```python
for name, group in df.groupby(['a','b']):
    df['ycalc'] = func(params[name],group['c'])
```

But then the whole column is overwritten for each group, yielding NaN for all members outside the group. Another logical solution would be to use transform, but then I cannot use the group name as input (regardless of possible other syntax mistakes):

```python
df['ycalc'] = df.groupby(['a','b'])['x'].transform(func, args=(params[name]))
```

What would be the best approach to get column ycalc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda function:

```
df['ycalc'] = df.groupby(['a','b'])['x'].transform(lambda x: func(x, p[x.name]))
```

Comment: Sometimes it is easier than one thinks... Your answer was so quick I could not accept it yet.

Comment: This works great for my example, but of course I over-simplified my actual problem. In my real problem I have multiple columns x that are called in func, e.g. 'x1', 'x2', and 'x3'. It seems that transform only passes one column at the time via lambda x and not the whole group. Should I use apply in that case, or is there a nice alternative that reshapes everything back into column format of the original df, like transform does?

Comment: @Adriaan - Hmm, so need processing same function for multiple columns? Like `df[['ycalc1', 'ycalc2', 'ycalc3']] = df.groupby(['a','b'])[['x1','x2','x3']].transform(lambda x: func(x, p[x.name]))` ?

Comment: No, there is only one output array, something like ``y += p[i]*df['x1']**(i) + p[i]*x['x2']**(i-1) + p[i]*x['x2']**(i-2)``, where ``func(x,p)`` becomes ``func(df,p)``, so I assume x is a dataframe. Let me know if this deviates too much from the original post, I can make it another question.

Comment: @Adriaan - I think `groupby.apply` is necessary, because `transform` cannot working with `x1`, `x2`, `x2` paralel, in `groupby.transform` with multiple columns like `df.groupby(['a','b'])[['x1','x2','x3']].transform()` is processing each column separately. So it means first `x1`, then `x2` and last `x3`

Comment: @jezrall Yes, I got that to work, my main issue was that I did not know one could call x.name. Now my only puzzle is reshaping it into a column again, I guess I have to transform and merge the result somehow.

Comment: @Adriaan - Then try `melt` for unpivot, then apply solution and last need `pivoting`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231975/discussion-between-adriaan-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion under the accepted answer, I share the solution that I finally used, proposed by jezrael as well:

```
def f(x):
    x['ycalc'] = func(params[x.name],x['c'])
    return x

df = df.groupby(['a','b']).apply(f)
```

For me this is more readable than using melt and pivoting (another suggestion) and it adds the extra flexibility of using multiple columns for the construction of `df['ycalc']`. This came in handy, because in my real problem I have columns `df['d']` and `df['e']` in addition to `df['c']` that are used as input for `func`.